# @Schedule won't work EJB - Java EE - Web application

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0

I am trying to use a simple @Schedule, so I can use it later on ...
My web app only contains an index.html
If I go to ./api/test/   I will go to my controller managed by EJB.
In this controller I call a method with a @Schedule annation. But I just don't understand how to get this to work ...
The runningscript method add the counter field by one so my index.html file display number: 1. But my number never goed higher, I don't even see any sysouts .. So I suppose my @schedule don't get triggered ?

This are my two only used code files:

```
@Path("/test")
public class controller {

NewClass test;

public controller() {
    test = new NewClass();
}

@GET
public Response getObservation() {
    try {
        //Object to JSON in String
        test.runningScript();
        System.out.println("getObservation");
        System.out.println(test.getText());
        String jsonInString = test.getText();
        return Response.status(200).entity(jsonInString).build();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("error");
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

class with scheduling

```
public class NewClass {

private int counter = 0;
private String text = "test";

public NewClass() {

}

public String getText(){
    return text;
}

private void setText(String text){
    this.text = text;
}


@Schedule(hour="*", minute="*", second="*/5")
public void runningScript() {
    counter++;
    System.out.println("*******test runningscript*****");
    System.out.println(counter);
    text = "number : " + counter;
}
}
```

Someone an Idea how I could get this to work ?
I searched for hours :ss

Comment: You typically should not call methods annotated with `@Schedule`.  What are you trying to do, and what's happening instead?

Comment: later on I want to read a script every x seconds, scheduled by @schedule ...

Comment: But I am now testing the use of @schedule. He don't even give my sysouts every 5 seconds If I run the method ? If I best don't call methods annoted with Schedule, how do I start them then ?

Comment: What's happening instead?  `@Schedule` should start running as soon as the module is started.  Perhaps you want TimerService.createCalendarTimer instead?

Comment: Maybe, but we are learning ejb and the @scheduling in school for using :s I will try it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NewClass` is not an EJB. `@Schedule` only works on EJBs.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Here is a sample:
https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/blob/master/ejb/timer/src/main/java/org/javaee7/ejb/timer/SchedulesTimerBean.java - replace the pingEvent with a log output to see it working in your logs.

Comment: Good catch.  More specifically, OP should remove the `controller` constructor, use `@Stateless public class NewClass`, and use `@EJB NewClass test` to inject the instance.

Comment: I thought, I tried this but nvm, It works. Thx alot !